# Importing UIViewController in XCTestCase class results different types of compiler errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am trying to write tests for a UIViewController but for some reason when i import the controller into the test case class, i start getting weird build errors. I have tried the following things so far:

1. I have tried adding the UIViewController to the test target. It has no effect on my compilation.
2. I have made sure that the General Tab of my Unit test Target says "Allow testing of host application API's"
3. I have checked various variables in my build settings such as Test Host, etc.
4. I am using Pods and have run the install again so that the Dependencies get added to the Test Target.
5. The test doesn't throw any compiler error if I import something else other than a UIViewController.

All of the above efforts have gone in vain and am still not able to figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Don't you think it would help to update your question with details about the errors and to show relevant code?

Comment: There is no code. I just add a new target and import a controller. Thats it. And errors are random. Everytimes its a different class with different error.

Comment: It throws errors in all those classes which are imported in my ViewController .